# Passing Value to Functions From ngOnInit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fabricjs, ngoninit

I have a button that calls **clip** function. I need to pass values from **ngOnInit** to that function but i can't. I get undefined error for (for example) **this.firstX**. How can i pass values from ngOnInit to functions?

```
export class AppAppComponent implements OnInit {

  public firstX: number;
  public firstY: number;
  public lastX: number;
  public lastY: number;

  constructor(mdIconRegistry: MdIconRegistry) {
    mdIconRegistry
      .registerFontClassAlias('fontawesome', 'fa');
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('cLeft');
    let src = "../../images/kupurSecond.jpg";

    canvas.on('mouse:down', function (event) {
      var position = canvas.getPointer(event.e);
      this.firstX = position.x;
      this.firstY = position.y;
    });

    canvas.on('mouse:up', function (event) {
      var position = canvas.getPointer(event.e);
      this.lastX = position.x;
      this.lastY = position.y;
      // ReLoading Image
      loadImage(src, canvas, this.firstX, this.firstY, this.lastX, this.lastY);
    });

    loadImage(src, canvas);

  }; 

  public clip() {
    console.log(this.firstX);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the arrow notation to remain the same `this` context.

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', (event) => {
      var position = canvas.getPointer(event.e);
      this.firstX = position.x;
      this.firstY = position.y;
});
```

Same goes for the `mouse:up` function. Just never use the word `function` in typescript, and you are golden